# Generating the next heatmap in a sequence of labelled heatmaps without assuming continuity

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gan

I have a sequence of labelled heatmaps and I want to generate a new heatmap that is the 'best guess' at what the next heatmap in the sequence will look like, without assuming that the next heatmap should have any 'continuity' with the previous heatmap (i.e. so not like frames of a video of someone walking, where there is generally continuity between one frame and the next).

As an example, these heatmaps could represent the areas of a 2D space where people spent most of their time in a given time interval.

My question is: what machine learning model would be best suited to predict the next heatmap in the sequence, knowing that 1) continuity with the previous heatmap should not be assumed (which potentially rules out those models that predict the next frame in a video), and 2) we want a 'best guess' at the next heatmap, not multiple different guesses in the same way that a conditional GAN designed to output handwritten digits would output different 1s or 5s each time?

Answer (score 1):

A conditional GAN would likely work. Many practical implementations of cGAN leave out the noise, on the basis that there is so much training data, it's unlikely the discriminator will notice that the generator only produces one output per conditional input. (Or, if you don't want to use this trick, you could query the GAN with multiple noise vectors and average all the outputs to get the "conditional mean").